# How to pass ILogger to my filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, exceptionfilterattribute

I have an ASP.NET Web APi Service.

I have added a global error exception routine using IExceptionFilter.

To register the service I have this in my StartUp.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter()); 
});
```

My Exception Filter Class is this:

```
public class ErrorHandlingFilter : ApiControllerBase, IExceptionFilter
{
    public ErrorHandlingFilter(ILogWriter logger) : base(logger)
    {

    }


    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {

        // If our exception has been handled, exit the function
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        // Set our handled property to true
        filterContext.Result = new StatusCodeResult(500);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

But, obviously, I get a compile error at this line here:

```
 options.Filters.Add(new ErrorHandlingFilter());
```

because it is expecting me to pass an instance of ILogger.

But I define Ilogger here:

```
// Add singleton instance to the application for the LogWriter class
services.AddSingleton<ILogWriter, LogWriter>();

// Add singleton instance to the application for the NLog Logger which is used within the LogWriter implementation
services.AddSingleton(typeof(ILogger), LogManager.GetLogger("WebApi.Host"));
```

So, how can I pass an instance to my Exception Filter without duplication?

NB
I admit this could be daft question, but it is very hot so brain is frazzled..

Comment: Why is your filter derived from `ApiControllerBase`?

Comment: Try using `options.Filters.Add<ErrorHandlingFilter>()` instead

Comment: [Dependency Injection in action filters in ASP.NET Core](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/dependency-injection-in-action-filters-in-asp.net-core)

Comment: There is also the option to add it by type `options.Filters.Add(typeof(ErrorHandlingFilter)); // by type`

Comment: Yeah obviously when using `new` you are required to pass valid constructors parameters so you have to use other overload to let the framework know it should handle creation using IoC container. There are countless ways of doing things in ASP.NET Core

Comment: @Nkosi hi sorry for delay in my response. It is abstract that handles logging. Something I have to use

Comment: @Konrad thanks. I will try this when back at desk. Been called away

Comment: @AndrewSimpson it is unusual to see a filter derived from `ApiControllerBase`

Comment: @Nkosi will try when back. Thanks

Comment: @Nkosi yes, their api controllers were using this base class to handle logging. Then I had a requirement to add a centralised logging pattern. Architecture looks awful, not sure what else to try?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson consider deriving from ExceptionFilterAttribute, , [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1#exception-filters)

Comment: Yes I did this originally but I thought using an interface would b better?

Comment: @Nkosi remember now. By using the interface I could also the abstract base class for logging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add your filter using `Add<T>`, this allows us to resolve the filter from the IoC container. This means your `ILogWriter` will be injected in for you on use of the filter.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ErrorHandlingFilter>(); 
});
```

On top of this as Nkosi comment says you can use `typeof` as well which will trigger the same behaviour as the above.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
  options.Filters.Add(typeof(ErrorHandlingFilter));
});
```